# Power Automate- Online form output to excel

Tags: power-automate

I am using a system that allows me to create forms for users to complete for various activities.

The form will be formatted in this manner

[image: Example of the form]

The form will be completed and can be used within power automate

When I tried to look at that output it comes out as shown below. On dynamic content it does not let me get individual field values.

[image: Output from Power automate]

There are a number of problems I have faced with this and would love to get some solutions to this.

What have I tried on power automate is this.

[image: Progress on Power automate]

What would I want?

1. To be able to see what choices the users have made and send an email to a person
2. To extract the choices made by the users and move it to an excel table.

Please can someone help me out.

Please see JSON Below:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
        "Host": "prod-04.westus.logic.azure.com",
        "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.27.1",
        "sentry-trace": "a9a8dd5467a14824b9f18125adc13e90-8a2eeed50e4259ae-",
        "x-datadog-trace-id": "2643934717261495620",
        "x-datadog-parent-id": "17259524742879917266",
        "x-datadog-sampling-priority": "0",
        "Content-Length": "1960",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "id": 815,
        "added_by": {
            "id": 135,
            "first_name": "Fahim",
            "last_name": "Mulla"
        },
        "contributors": [
            {
                "id": 135,
                "first_name": "Fahim",
                "last_name": "Mulla"
            }
        ],
        "created": "2022-03-22T09:19:53.435738Z",
        "last_modified_by": {
            "id": 135,
            "first_name": "Fahim",
            "last_name": "Mulla"
        },
        "modified": "2022-03-22T09:19:57.425778Z",
        "referenced_object": 73,
        "referenced_object_type": "productionline",
        "status": "in_progress",
        "template": {
            "id": 341,
            "name": "Test"
        },
        "template_version": "13.0.0",
        "completion_version": {
            "id": 8661,
            "number": "0.1.0",
            "actions": [
                "auto_save",
                "in_progress"
            ]
        },
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 704,
                "type": "header",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 705,
                "type": "datetime",
                "value": "2022-03-22T09:19:00Z"
            },
            {
                "id": 706,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": [
                    10002447
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 707,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": [
                    10002449
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 708,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 709,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 710,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 711,
                "type": "text",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 712,
                "type": "text",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 713,
                "type": "text",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 714,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 715,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 716,
                "type": "text",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 717,
                "type": "text",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 718,
                "type": "text",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 720,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 722,
                "type": "media",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 723,
                "type": "text",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 724,
                "type": "text",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 725,
                "type": "checkbox",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 726,
                "type": "checkbox",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 727,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 728,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 729,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 730,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 731,
                "type": "text",
                "value": null
            },
            {
                "id": 732,
                "type": "choice",
                "value": []
            },
            {
                "id": 733,
                "type": "signature",
                "value": null
            }
        ],
        "has_deviation": false,
        "deviation_count": 0
    }
}
```

[image: Excel example]

For the excel document the originator would be the contributor. The date raised is date created. The type of concern/Type of issue/Location/Category of failure mode/Risk Rating are the choices the user will need to select.

The description of issue/ what happened/ immediate actions taken are text that are inputted by the person filling the form.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the JSON that is the response to your form submission? I see the screenshot but more context would be nice.

Comment: Hi @Skin, Please see the Question- I have added the JSON for the form.

Comment: Ok, next question, given the JSON you've provided, can you give an example of what you want the Excel table to look like?

Comment: @Skin I have updated the post to show the excel format. Ideally I want to be able to extract the choices/text from the form into excel. Looking forward to your response.

Comment: The point of the example was to show how the data in your JSON maps to Excel and it doesn't do that.  The thing with your data is that there are gaps everywhere and because of the way the submission is structured, there are ID's for the questions and no column names, therefore, how does it all map?  The point of Stackoverflow is to help with a specific issue, not have the code/solution built for you and at the minute, your questions can't be answered without way more information and more targeted questions.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Skin I understand, so could we focus on one specific question which is, from the output IDs that the user has selected, how can extract that just in power automate. For example 10002447 is for Safety, how can I show that the user has selected that and change the output to show it as a text